# OpenGL: How to control which buffering method my window will use?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, opengl

I want to give the user ability to choose from double buffering and triple buffering, because on some cards (or OS?) the triple buffering is enabled by default, and its causing some performance problems.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this from OpenGL itself, since OpenGL only deals with drawing calls, etc. You need to use the vendor specific calls for this. In Windows, there is the WGL for handling context creation, etc.

Comment: Really? im sure ive seen double/triple buffer options in some games. Can you give some link to the WGL page where i can find the information needed to do what i want?

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Swap_Interval but this is related only loosely to triple buffering.

Comment: @Rookie: You probably have- in Direct3D you can have as many buffers as you like.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such function in OpenGL.

The closest what I found is [glutInitDisplayMode](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node12.html), where you can pass `GLUT_DOUBLE` or `GLUT_SINGLE` to enable or disable double buffering. Other window managers, like for example SDL have other call :

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
```

Comment: is there something non-glut way to do this? i heard glut is deprecated and etc i should never use it etc. (i hear this a lot.)

Comment: @Rookie What are you using to create a window to render your image? Whatever you are using it has a function to set the buffering mode. My answer also tells how it is done in the SDL

Comment: @Rookie: `GLUT` and `SDL` are both open-source, just trace the function calls back until you get to where they call into the operating-system-specific routines.

Comment: i guess you mean this: `static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = { ... PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,` But it only stands for "Must Support Double Buffering", it does not _force_ me to use doublebuffering instead of triplebuffering.

Comment: @genpfault: i tracked it at `*iAttr++ = WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB; *iAttr++ = this->gl_config.double_buffer;` but im not sure how to use this with my `static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` thingie. I tried replacing `PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER` with `WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB` but it had no effect at all.