# Few questions about multiple buffering in OpenGL on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, opengl, 3d

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827570/opengl-how-to-control-which-buffering-method-my-window-will-use) but it says nothing about triple buffering and the actual methods.

1. What is the most common way modern games perform triple buffering ?
2. What does the [SwapBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd369060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) exactly do in terms of OpenGL states ?
3. Is it possible to perform double and triple buffering independently of window system (for example, by manipulating with glDrawBuffer or by using FBO/PBO) ?
4. Does 3. even make sense in terms of performance and flexibility ?

Answer (score 3):

As per [OpenGL common mistakes on triple buffering](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Triple_Buffering):

> You cannot control whether a driver does triple buffering. You could try to implement it yourself using a FBO. But if the driver is already doing triple buffering, your code will only turn it into quadruple buffering. Which is usually overkill.

`SwapBuffers` instructs the driver to swap or copy between the front and back buffer, it is not an OpenGL command.